# Сумма всех data-price

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть вкладки, у каждой вкладки есть data-price, так же в каждой вкладке есть по 2 радиокнопки, data-price вкладки меняется в зависимости от выбранной радиокнопки, все прекрасно работает.
Теперь ступор: есть блок, куда должна выводиться сумма всех data-price вкладок, при том она должна изменяться если в какой то из вкладок выбрать другую радиокнопку. Не могу понять как это сделать. Хелп

UPD: Разобрался сам. Но вылезла другая проблема, все считается как строка 
7500 + 1000 = 75001000. Как преобразовать?

```
function get_allsum(){
                    var allsum = 0;
                    $('[data-price]').each(function(){
                        allsum += $(this).attr('data-price');
                    });
                    $('#fPrice').html(allsum);
               }
```

Решил обе проблемы, если кому пригодиться.

```
function get_allsum(){
      var allsum = 0;
      $('[data-price]').each(function(){
          allsum += Number($(this).attr('data-price'));
      });
      $('#fPrice').html(allsum + "<i> ₽</i>");
}
```

Comment: Что бы мы могли вам помочь, вам надо показать нам код, который у вас есть. И код, которым вы пытались решить задачу.

Comment: Спасибо,с этим разобрался всплыла другая проблема

Comment: Уверен, с другой тоже разберетесь. Кстати, если разобрались, то можете опубликовать ответ на свой вопрос - может кому-то в будущем он пригодится.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Ответ тоже выложил) Надеюсь кому то пригодиться

Comment: Ответ лучше оформить ответом)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_allsum(){
      var allsum = 0;
      $('[data-price]').each(function(){
          allsum += Number($(this).attr('data-price'));
      });
      $('#fPrice').html(allsum + "<i> ₽</i>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> allsum += $(this).attr('data-price');
> ```

```
allsum += +$(this).data('price');
```